# Every question asked on this site can be researched and answered independently

Tags: discussion

I was asked to research my question which was direct and simple while my questions were down voted? So what is the point of Stack Exchanges ask a question get an answer, or this site, if every question can be researched and answered without this site?

Answer (score 8):

The purpose of any Q&A site is not to do your research for you. If you try to get by without Q&A sites like Bio.SE, you will sooner or later notice why they really exist. It's because you *can't* answer all questions without them. You can *research* any question without them, but at some point it may simply be impossible to find an answer without some help.

Asking on Bio.SE is no different than asking an expert personally - if you don't make it clear why it is that you need an expert to make the effort, they won't bother. Give the expert a reason as to what makes them uniquely able to help you out, and they just might. As for the "why", there are always only those two reasons: a) the knowledge isn't publically available, or b) it would take you days to find out whereas the expert can answer in minutes.